# How to assign default values ​​for an edit form?

Tags: forms

In my form I create a field of type list (with the widget box is checked). By default, this field has no value.

In my hook_form_alter () method, I add options (via PHP) has this field.

```
$form['field_genric_domains']['und']['#options']= _get_domaine_options();

if($form['field_genric_domains']['und']['#default_value'] == NULL){ 
    $form['field_genric_domains']['und']['#default_value']  = array(_get_this_domain_id());
}
```

Then I set a default value. I set up a test that shows whether we are editing or creating.

When creating, it works perfectly, but when editing the table (# default_value) is empty. Normally it should contain the values ​​previously inquire.

Why? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found!
Made in, when loading a form, drupal will verify that the value is in # default_value also found in # options. If it does not find a match it displays an empty table.

As the set of options and # # default_value is in the code, you must override the operation of drupal and make the comparison in the code before displaying

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that value returned by _get_this_domain_id() function is in the array key used to create #options for form element ['field_genric_domains'] .

Example :

If _get_domaine_options() function returns array as :

array(1=>'India',2=>'USA');

Then _get_this_domain_id() should return key either 1 or 2 .That will set the default value depending on the array key .

Comment: It is good, it is not error.
The _get_domaine_options () function allows me to retrieve a list of field (array (1 => 'domain.fr', 2 => 'domain.com', 3 => 'domain.de).
The _get_this_domain_id () function returns the id of the current domain. The current domain is included in the list of options.

Comment: Then it should work properly . One more think check if _get_this_domain_id() is returning only the Id value and not complete array.

Comment: The _get_this_domain_id () function returns an integer that I inserted into a table.
Before the end of my hook_form_alter () method, I put a var_dump that returns me an array array (0 => 1)

Comment: Another ideas ?

Comment: Can you paste your form-alter code here ? or may be that if condition that checks for NULL would be causing that problem try removing it .